# I'm trying ro make this function and trigger work:

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, pgadmin-4

I have a table with users where there is a colum with phone numbers and another colum with an ID and another table with calls where there are phones and the ID of the user who called (if users call will have the same id for the two tables). Now I need to do a function and a trigger that updates the phone number from the table users when the ID of the user who called is the same ID from a user who is in the table users.
The problem is that when I insert values into the table calls (with the same IDs from users) the phone number doesnt update.

My function and my trigger:

```
--Function:

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION validate_phones() RETURNS trigger AS $$
BEGIN
        UPDATE matchdotcom.user 
        SET matchdotcom.user.phonenumber = 
(SELECT NEW.v.phone_number
FROM matchdotcom.calls v, matchdotcom.user u ) 
WHERE NEW.calls.user_id = matchdotcom.user.iduser
;
RETURN update_phone;
   END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


--Trigger:


CREATE TRIGGER update_phone
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON matchdotcom.calls
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE validate_phones();
```

Thank you for helping me with this :)

Comment: Hard to list all you are doing wrong: 1) The SQL statement makes so little sense that I cannot divine what you intend to do 2) Such a subquery must not return more than one row 3) you return something different from a table row.

Comment: When asking a question, sample data and desired results are often very helpful.